# Access to Sourcegraph is forbidden because no authentication provider is set in site configuration

Tags: sourcegraph

I was configuring authentication for a third party in Sourcegraph and did a SAVE when it told me I needed to have enterprise version.  I then deleted the authentication provider section in administration and saved it.  Did a restart and received message 'Access to Sourcegraph is forbidden because no authentication provider is set in site configuration.' on the web page.  I deleted DOCKER, deleted docker folder in /var/lib,  Reinstalled docker and then did another quickstart of sourcegraph.  Received the raph.same message again when I went to web page for sourcegraph.  I must not be getting a fresh copy of something.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I determined that there is a .sourcegraph directory in the home directory of root (the user I was logged inas when sourcegraph was installed) that contains configuration data.  Wiped out that directory and then reinstalled and everything worked.

Comment: Sourcegraph CTO here, sorry to hear you had trouble with this. Should this happen again, instead of deleting the entire .sourcegraph directory (which deletes all data), you could also edit .sourcegraph/config/sourcegraph-config.json to include the appropriate auth provider and restart the server. (Note: this will change in the future as we move the source of truth for config into the database, but for now, it should work.)